# Improve nested loop for bio-statistics calculation

Tags: c++, optimization, c, statistics

I am doing a bio-statistics calculation and the following code works. However, can someone help to improve the messy nested loop?

```
for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<NN; j++) {
        if (i != j){
            thirdlayer = 0;
            for (int k=0; k<NN; k++) {
                fourthlayer = 0;
                for (int l=0; l<NN; l++) {
                    fourthlayer =  fourthlayer + V[j*NN+l]*V[NN+l]*J[k*NN+l];
                }
                thirdlayer = thirdlayer + V[k]*V[i*NN+k]*fourthlayer;
            }
            if(pi_cod[j] != 0)
                Transitions[i*NN +j] =  sqrt(pi_cod[i]*pi_cod[1]/(pi_cod[0]*pi_cod[j]))*Q[i*NN +j]*thirdlayer/Padt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like matrix multiplication. What are `V`, `J`, `pi_cod`, and `Transitions`? Why is `sqrt()` involved in matrix multiplication?

Comment: @200_success: I'd also like to know if this is C or C++.  The `sqrt()` tells me it's the latter (assuming `std::` was left out), but looking at the rest of the code, I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jamal I think it's `C`.

Comment: The `fourthlayer` values don't depend on `i`, so you could precompute them for every `j` and `k`. This should reduce time complexity from `O(NN^4)` to `O(NN^3)`.

Comment: @200_success Sorry I said wrong. It is no matrix multiplication, it's some biol statistic algorithm.

Comment: @Jamal It is written initially in C and then switched to c++. However, i don't think this matters much here

Comment: @nwellnhof the fourthlayer computed by `V[j*NN+1]` and `J[k*NN+l]` which depends on j and k. Could you show me sample code that to factor fourthlayr computation way out?

Comment: Are you sure `fourthlayer + V[j*NN+l]*V[NN+l]*J[k*NN+l]` is correct? The index of the second factor, `NN + l`, is suspicious, because it means that the second "row" of `V` is somehow special.

Comment: Similarly, the `[k]` in `V[k]` is suspicious.

Comment: @200_success Yes, in this case it is. However, the code below is not correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Using small `l` for the index is bad because it looks like the digit 1.  It's better to use large `L`.

Instead of `j*NN`, it's better to use a cached index that increments by `for`:

```
int NN2 = NN*NN
for(int iNN=k; iNN < (NN2+k); iNN+=NN) {
  thirdlayer = thirdlayer + V[k]*V[iNN]*fourthlayer;
}
```

This could be a bit faster.

Another hook - more use pointer as array sintax:
for 3layer better get a row vector in wich 4layer for process:

```
int* VVj = &(V[j*NN]);
int* VNN = &(V[NN]);
for (int k=0; k<NN; k++) {
                int* JNNk = &(J[k*NN]);
                fourthlayer = 0;
                for (int l=0; l<NN; l++) {
                    fourthlayer =  fourthlayer + VVj[l]*VNN[l]*JNNk[l];
                }
                thirdlayer = thirdlayer + V[k]*V[i*NN+k]*fourthlayer;
            }
```

good compiler do it for you byself, but in such decomposition may better see data dependents, and it is a bit simpler and short

also you can deploy from 4layer V[j*NN+l]*V[NN+l] into stanalone vector that can be prepared in outer j cycle.

Instead of division `(xxx)/Padt` (better=faster), use multiplication `*(1/Padt)`, or move out from the last cycle:

```
double thp = thirdlayer/Padt;
for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) { 
    if(i != j && pi_cod[j] != 0)
      Transitions[i*NN +j] =  sqrt(pi_cod[i]*pi_cod[1]/(pi_cod[0]*pi_cod[j]))*Q[i*NN +j]*thp;
  }
```

Instead of a conditional calculation, it's better to use a conditional assignment since it can better optimized for x86:

```
double thp = thirdlayer/Padt;
for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) {
    int pcodj = (pi_cod[j] != 0)?pi_cod[j]: 1;
    double transition = sqrt(pi_cod[i]*pi_cod[1]/(pi_cod[0]*pi_cod[j]))*Q[i*NN +j]*thp;
    if(i != j && pi_cod[j] != 0)
      Transitions[i*NN +j] = transition;
  }
```

If it's rare misses for assignment, so penalty for calculation could be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. Though I suspect your compiler *might* have been doing this already.

```
for (int j=0; j<NN; j++) {
  thirdlayer = 0;
  for (int k=0; k<NN; k++) {
    fourthlayer = 0;
    for (int l=0; l<NN; l++) {
      fourthlayer =  fourthlayer + V[j*NN+l]*V[NN+l]*J[k*NN+l];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) {
      thirdlayer = thirdlayer + V[k]*V[i*NN+k]*fourthlayer;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) { 
    if(i != j && pi_cod[j] != 0)
      Transitions[i*NN +j] =  sqrt(pi_cod[i]*pi_cod[1]/(pi_cod[0]*pi_cod[j]))*Q[i*NN +j]*thirdlayer/Padt;
  }
}
```

This is what nwellnhof meant. Now there are only 3 levels of nesting loops.

Comment: OK. I carefully looked into that and realized it was not correct way to re-factory the code at all

Answer (score 0):

removed the layer from 3rd and 4th because it made things annoyingly long, but moved some of the initializers into the for() and precomputed some x*NN, changed the a = a +... to a+=... and moved the 4 layer into its for loop (thus the trailing semicolon)

```
for(int i=0, iN=0; i<NN; i++, iN=i*NN) {
  for(int j=0, third=0, jN=0; j<NN; j++, jN=j*NN, third=0) {
    for(int k=0, fourth=0, kN=0; i!=j && k<NN; third += V[k]*V[iN+k]*fourth, k++, kN=k*NN)
      for(int l=0, jN=j*NN; l<NN; fourth+=V[jN+l]*V[NN+l]*J[kN+l], l++);
    if (i!=j && pi_cod[j] != 0)
      Transitions[iN+j]=sqrt(pi_cod[i]*pi_cod[1]/(pi_cod[0]*pi_cod[j]))*Q[iN+j]*third/Padt;
  }
}
```

Comment: the loop initialized fourth cannot be used outside `l` loop, so `third+=..*fourth` fails. Similarly, `iN` and `jN` in `Transitions[iN+j]` also fails as they are random number in this scope.

Comment: Thanks for editing. But the logical is still not right as it generates different result. Also, the running time seems even slower than original code